# Ajax in Django is creating duplicate elements

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a form which when submitted creates a graph using Plotly. I am trying to use `Ajax` to submit the form without page refresh. While the form is submitted successfully, the form div is duplicated on the screen. I am not sure how to rectify this problem. I am using the Django web framework. Here is my code.

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method='post' id='year-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 dropdown-btn" aria-label="Default select example"
        name="year">
        <option selected>Select Year</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Button</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>

<div class="graph center" id='graph'>
    {% if graph %}
    {{ graph.0|safe }}
    {% else %}
    <p>No graph was provided.</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**ajax jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#year-form');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#graph").html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#message").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

This is what the page looks like before the form submit

[image]

this is what it looks like after the form is submitted

[image]

I think I am not feeding the correct data in the `success` part of the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different endpoint/view to return the graph template. At the moment you are getting the current page and loading it again but with a graph this time.

Your home template should be:

```html
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method='post' id='year-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 dropdown-btn" aria-label="Default select example"
        name="year">
        <option selected>Select Year</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Button</button>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>

<div class="graph center" id='graph'>
    <p>No graph was provided.</p>
</div>
```

Then you have a second template used at a different view which you get via ajax to get the graph like so:

```html
{% if graph %}
    {{ graph.0|safe }}
{% else %}
    <p>No graph was provided.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But having a different view will take me to a different page correct? How do I render the graph in the same page?

Comment: Your using ajax so you shouldn't have that problem, if it is doing this, try adding `frm.submit(function (e) => { e.preventDefault() ...}` to stop the form submitting and posting the the view

Comment: Could you explain? your solution worked before but I am now facing the issue again. I am trying to add more charts and it stopped working